# How to prove the following formula of both side is comparable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to prove the following formula of both side is comparable? $u\in W_p^2(R^n),W_p^2(R^n)$ is Sobolev space. Then prove the following formula are comparable?
$$\|\Delta u\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p}\asymp \sum_{|\alpha|\leq2}\|\partial^\alpha u\|_{L^p}.$$
$\|\Delta u\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p}\leq \|\partial^\alpha u\|_{L^p}$ is trivially. Conversely, we have $\|u\|_{L^p},\|\Delta u\|_{L^p}, \sum_{i=1}\|\nabla_iu\|_{L^p}, \sum_{i\neq j=1}\|\nabla_iu\nabla_ju\|_{L^p}.$ The first part and the second part is trivially. How to deal with the interection term?

Comment: In what context are you interested in this "formula"? What have you tried?

Comment: I try to estimate the fractional Laplace operator.

Comment: Are you some idea to show it?

Comment: One side is trivially bounded by the other. The other bound follows from the boundedness of Riesz transforms for finite p. Also there are no fractional Laplace operators

Comment: Yes, I already got the right side of results for the estimate. I want to show the left side. So I need to show there are comparable. Thanks for your trick.

Comment: It would be nice if you can give me some detail that how to use the boundedness of Riesz transfroms for finite p to estimate the non-trivially side.

Comment: Basically combine two results (a) an interpolation equality $\lVert\nabla u\rVert_p^2\leq C_{p,n}\lVert\nabla^2 u\rVert_p\cdot\lVert u\rVert_p$ and (b) control the norm of Hessian by the norm of the Laplacian by Caderon-Zygmund for compactly supported functions.

Comment: Sorry, I can not see the results immediately. Can you explain a little bit  more b)?